# Angular - Show loading spinner till methods finish execution

Tags: angular, angular7

I got two methods which each takes a couple of seconds to execute. I want to show a spinner while the data is being loaded and stop the spinner only after both methods have finished execution.

Since the methods are asynchronous, currently, the spinner doesn't wait for the methods to complete. It just shows and then hides it self before the methods finish execution.

Following is my code. What can I do to run the spinner till both methods finish execution?

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.spinner.show();

    this.getAllCalendars();
    this.loadHolidayData();

    this.spinner.hide();
  }


  loadHolidayData() {    

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

      //Get holiday data

    });

  }


  getAllCalendars() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

      //Get calendar data

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `forkJoin`, or `combineLatest`, depending on your requirements.

`forkJoin` emits the results once all observables are completed, while `combineLatest` emits the latest values from each observable. `route.queryParams` will never be completed, as route parameters can be updated upon routing to different pages, or when the user changes the URL address. Therefore, `combineLatest` works better for your scenario.

Remember to import [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) or [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) on your component.ts. I am not sure how exactly does  your this.spinner.show() works, but I have added `isLoading` as the boolean value to check if it is loading or not. 
On your component.html,

```
<spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></spinner>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
.
.
.
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllData();
  }

loadAllData() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.isLoading = true;
  const combined = combineLatest(
      this.route.queryParams(),
     // your service api method calls
    ).pipe(
      map(([params1, params2]) => ({...params1, ...params2}))
  );

  combined.subscribe(result => { 
    console.log(result)
    // hide spinner once loading is completed
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, Thank you for the answer. I tried this but 'combined.subscribe' is never being called. Any reason?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I have updated my answer. I think combineLatest works better in this case. I will explain on the answer.

Comment: Hey, I tried combineLatest  too but still the same effect. it's not going inside 'combined.subscribe'

Comment: Hmm.. I have updated it again. Can you try it this time round?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest` and `finally` to make the spinner hide when both Observables are completed (either failed or succeeded).

Please notice that for the example to work, both functions `loadHolidayData()` and `getAllCalendars()` should return an Observable. Hope it helps.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
}

loadData() {
    this.spinner.show();

    combineLatest([this.loadHolidayData(), this.getAllCalendars()])
        .finally(() => this.spinner.hide())
        .takeUntil(() => this.destroyed$())
        .subscribe(([loadHolidayDataResponse, getAllCalendarsResponse]) => {
            // do your stuff here 
        });

}
```